# How to show progress bar of achieved target?

Tags: vba, ms-access, progress-bar

I am building a database with Sales Employees that have a monthly target to achieve.

I want to make a progress bar that is shown to the user in main menu, with information on how much has been achieved of the monthly target from a table, and sum of their sales from another table.

For example, like in the picture below, if the employee achieved 1250$ out of a 5000$ target, then the progress bar stops at 25%.
[image]

I tried to modify the example code here.
[enter link description here](http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/progress-bar/4594424316)

Comment: What does "failed" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Edit question to show your attempted code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a progress bar showing status of code processing. You just want to graphically represent percentage completion of data target. This can easily be done with a graph control. Graph can dynamically display result for each record with appropriate WHERE clause in graph RowSource and no VBA should be required.

Alternatively, VBA code controls width of a textbox (or box control) with different color background over another control. Create two controls with width of 2 inches. In VBA, width property is measured in TWIPS -- 1 inch = 1440 TWIPS. Place code in form Current event. Be aware this will only work nicely for form in Single view because all records will have the same display.

`Me.Text3.Width = completed / target * 2880`

For a report, put code in Format event of section with these 2 controls. This will only work for report in PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView.

Now figure out how to get the data onto form or report. Have a RecordSource that is a query summarizing sales joined to target table or bind form to Employees table and use DSum() and DLookup() domain aggregate functions.